# Выделение памяти для массива до выполнения на С++

Tags: массивы, компилятор, g++

Всё работает. Хочу уточнить, как оно работает. :)

```
// Объявляю переменные размера массива
int mX = 10;
int mY = 20;

// Объявляю массив и указываю в параметрах переменные
int z[mX][mY];
```

Компилируется и работает. Получается, что g++ во время компиляции выполняет подстановку? Но при этом он её ещё как-то выполняет? Как он узнает, что mX это переменная и какое у неё значение? Или в массиве создаются ссылки на схожее название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная штука от gcc - [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/195148/).

> Получается, что g++ во время компиляции выполняет подстановку?

А кто ему мешает это сделать? Значение переменных известно. Если компилятор видит, что значение переменных не изменяется (то есть, это просто такие константы), то может во время компиляции выделить место.

> Но при этом он её ещё как-то выполняет?

Это объявление, оно не выполняется. Хотя, если переменные меняются, то память будет выделятся уже в процессе выполнения (и скорее всего на стеке. А там это просто сделать).

> Как он узнает, что mX это переменная и какое у неё значение?

Если бы компилятор этого не знал, то он бы не смог скомпилировать программу. Компилятор знает о каждой переменной в коде. Если он с какой-то переменной не может разобраться - он будет ругаться. Точно также и с функциями, классами и тому подобное.

> Или в массиве создаются ссылки на схожее название?

А вот этого я уже не понимаю:)

Answer (score 0):

Более того, такой код:

```
  int nx, ny, i, j;
  puts("enter nx ny");
  scanf("%d %d", &nx, &ny);

  int a[nx][ny];
  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < ny; j++)
      a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
```

в gcc/g++ тоже работает, хотя значения `nx` и `ny` во время компиляции неизвестны.

**Массивы перемнной длины (VLA)** это давно известное расширение GNU

(IMHO теперь стандаризовнное в C99).

Похожий низкоуровневый механизм динамического выделения памяти в стеке также обеспечивает функция `alloca()`.

Существенная разница в том, что "время жизни" памяти, выделенной `alloca()` всегда ограничено выходом (return) из всей функции, а для VLA оно определяется областью видимости  переменных, задающих размер VLA (и самого массива, естественно).

Кстати, вот в таком коде

```
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     int a[i + 10];
     ....
  }
```

на каждой итерации будет создаваться (где-то в стеке) новый массив размером `(i + 10) * sizeof(int)` байт.

В рамках одной функции смешивать `alloca()` и VLA не рекомдуется.